# Связка TinyMCE и БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Как связать TinyMCE и БД MySQL? Сколько ни читаю в инете - ничего понять не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подключения tinyMCE между <head> и </head> ставим

```
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->
```

Само собой, ложим папку с редактором туда, куда показывает путь в выше приведенном коде. Это все делается уже тогда, когда у вас есть рабочая страница, которая отправляет формы и корректно вбивает их в базу даных. Редактор автоматом найдет textarea на странице и подгрузится в них.

Comment: Подключить не получается
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->
</head>
</html>
И никак

Comment: отращивайте руки.. никогда не любил эту фразу, но тут могу сказать только это.

Comment: ХD Но я не могу все таки врубиться как его подключить.....

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="show.php">
   <p>     
     <textarea name="text" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
   </p>
</form>
```

Первая часть кода:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas"
});
```

"откомпилирует" все поля textarea в форматируемые поля. А в на сервер посылаете переменную text - название поля textarea. То есть:

```
$text=$_POST['text'];
```

Переменную $text можете сохранять в БД в поле типа TEXT.

Comment: Еще глупее вопрос- как подключить этот TinyMCE? что то тыкаюсь и нифига

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE - это просто textarea, так что ничего не мешает выводить информацию (текст) из БД в этот самый textarea, редактировать там и снова вносить в базу данных.