# Как подключить этот TinyMCE?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Как подключить этот TinyMCE?

[image: снимок 1]

[image: снимок 2]

Comment: 1.а где сама textarea?
2.где находится физически (полный путь) папка с редактором?

Comment: Путь - 5 строка. Какая текст ареа? она в самом шаблоне же есть?

Answer (score 1):

[Я же вам ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26752/%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-tinymce-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B4-mysql) настолько детально, насколько это возможно.

Comment: Я все сделал по вашему но где кнопки?

Comment: 1. Покажите код, который стоит в хеде.
2. Относительный путь до папки с редактором.

Comment: Смотрите ниже. Без шапки тоже не пашет. Код подключон правильно - при нажатии на ссылку выдает код библиотеки

Comment: 1. самый реальный вариант - косяки с путями до сорса tiny
2. отключен javascript
больше можете ничего не искать.. лбо 1 - либо 2

Answer (score 0):

```
/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
```

проверьте, есчть ли по этому пути файл tiny_mce.js, если есть то в строке:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

уберите первый слеш с /tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по путям -

```
c:\xampplite\htdocs\12.php
```

и

```
/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
```

файл javascript не грузится к клиенту.

Comment: Заработало!........

Answer (score -1):

Воспользоваться гуглом религия не позволяет?
[Перейди и нажми - View Source](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)

Comment: Я там и смотрел, но не получается.
Просто выводит текст ареа. А где кнопки и тд?

Comment: А вы все файлы подключили к сайту? (яваскриптовские). Покажите что вы делаете

Comment: Файл 12.php. Туда вставляю код, что на http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php, указываю путь к папке `<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>` свой путь. И нифига.